# Run go app by service

Tags: go, service, centos, command

In CentOS 6.8 I have a golang app , that run in command `go run main.go` and I need to create a system service to run it in boot like service httpd.
I know that I have to create file like `/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd` But I don't know how to do it to run that command.

Comment: This should help guide you:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236084/how-do-i-create-a-service-for-a-shell-script-so-i-can-start-and-stop-it-like-a-d

Comment: Golang app mean web app or system app?

Comment: @KyawMyintThein web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to build your Go binary and put it in your path.

```
go install main.go
```

If your "main" file is called main, `go install` will place a binary called "main" in your path, so I suggest you rename your file to whatever you call your project/server.

```
mv main.go coolserver.go
go install coolserver.go
```

You can run `coolserver` to make sure everything is fine. It will if you have your $GOPATH setup properly.

Here it is an example of a init.d service called `service.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          <NAME>
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $named $time $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Description:       <DESCRIPTION>
### END INIT INFO

SCRIPT=<COMMAND>
FLAGS="--auth=user:password"
RUNAS=<USERNAME>

PIDFILE=/var/run/<NAME>.pid
LOGFILE=/var/log/<NAME>.log

start() {
  if [ -f /var/run/$PIDNAME ] && kill -0 $(cat /var/run/$PIDNAME); then
    echo 'Service already running' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo 'Starting service…' >&2
  local CMD="$SCRIPT  $FLAGS &> \"$LOGFILE\" & echo \$!"
  su -c "$CMD" $RUNAS > "$PIDFILE"
  echo 'Service started' >&2
}

stop() {
  if [ ! -f "$PIDFILE" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat "$PIDFILE"); then
    echo 'Service not running' >&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo 'Stopping service…' >&2
  kill -15 $(cat "$PIDFILE") && rm -f "$PIDFILE"
  echo 'Service stopped' >&2
}

uninstall() {
  echo -n "Are you really sure you want to uninstall this service? That cannot be undone. [yes|No] "
  local SURE
  read SURE
  if [ "$SURE" = "yes" ]; then
    stop
    rm -f "$PIDFILE"
    echo "Notice: log file is not be removed: '$LOGFILE'" >&2
    update-rc.d -f <NAME> remove
    rm -fv "$0"
  fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  uninstall)
    uninstall
    ;;
  restart)
    stop
    start
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|uninstall}"
esac
```

Copy to /etc/init.d:

```
cp "service.sh" "/etc/init.d/coolserver"
chmod +x /etc/init.d/coolserver
```

## Remember to replace

```
<NAME> = coolserver
<DESCRIPTION> = Describe your service here (be concise)
<COMMAND> = /path/to/coolserver
<USER> = Login of the system user the script should be run as
```

Start and test your service and install the service to be run at boot-time:

```
service coolserver start
service coolserver stop
update-rc.d coolserver defaults
```

Comment: Well. that's the problem , CentOS 6.8 don't have systemd.
So your `systemctl` code will not work.

Comment: how about now @AliCoder ?

Comment: yes that's it, I have just a problem that `update-rc.d coolserver defaults` give me `update-rc.d command not found`, also How can I put parameters like `--auth "user:password"`

Comment: @AliCoder add the flags to your <COMMAND>, as you would on the command line. Things are a lil different on CentOs, I do not have a box to test this with, but read this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel5-update-rcd-command/

Comment: I did it `/path/to/coolserver --auth "user:password"` and it give me  `-auth: command not found`

Comment: I have edited the answer for completness http://serverfault.com/questions/462067/passing-arguments-to-a-service-started-with-init-d

Comment: nice. Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

I assume you tried to use apache web server. Actually, Go web server is enough itself. Main purpose is to run Go web server in system service.So, you can use **tmux** https://tmux.github.io/ or **nohup** to run as system service. You can also use apache or nginx web server as proxy.

Comment: I said httpd as an example , of course Go web server is enough itself,
What I need is create a service file  for centos 6 to run the app.
Somthing like that https://github.com/jpillora/cloud-torrent/wiki/Installation but in centos 6 because it's not has systemd.